# Power-off / Reboot dialog gnome-session-quit regression in 22.04

Tags: 20.04, gnome, shutdown, 22.04

In 20.04 I have mapped CTLR ALT Delete to

```
gnome-session-quit --reboot --power-off
```

[image: 20.04]

That isn't possible anymore in 22.04, I only get the first parameter (reboot) option.

[image: 22.04]

And that regression is IMHO a serious UI nuisance.

Is there a way to get the old behavior back, without using another shortcut, (or should I file a bug/feature request against `gnome-session-quit`)

Comment: Hi, you wanted to have reboot n power off options in one prompt?

Comment: Yes, like the first 20.04 dialog image, that doesn't show inline for some reason, just click it.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:

- install yad  (sudo apt install yad)
- assign this command to your shortcut:

  /usr/bin/bash -c 'MYOP=$(yad --timeout-indicator=top --timeout=10 --button=OK --entry --title="Methode" --text="Choose Methode " \logout power-off reboot || echo escaped) ; [[ $MYOP == escaped ]] || gnome-session-quit --$MYOP'

Answer (score 0):

### Workarounds

Collected some workarounds.

#### Another keyboard shortcut

This is what I did. I set up another shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to `gnome-session-quit  --reboot`, and I'm totally used to that nowadays.

### Gnome-extension

Another workaround is using this gnome-extension:
[Bring Out Submenu Of Power Off Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2917/bring-out-submenu-of-power-offlogout-button/)
Maybe that is also a good solution, functionality simply moved to an extension.

### Shell-script

The answer given by @Peter Petrekanics  using `yad`